# FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error getting in some browsers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing Web Application with firebase database. I am getting data from firebase in some browser's like firefox in windows. When I run in chrome or linux based OS systems it shows error. I can't understand The Error.

```html
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCZnHshgjfhgvjgvnvghjgjhghggh",
    authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "example-10aea",
    storageBucket: "example-10aea.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1234567899876"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
   firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
 console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
```

```html
Error : 

FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. @http://192.168.0.17:8080/ivinapp/viewmobiletrackingPage:134:13
g.Tb/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:468:829
fc@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:332:165
bf@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:397:215
cf@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:396:403
g.Gb@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:487:287
g.wd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:451:246
og.prototype.wd@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:441:359
qg/<@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:439:279
ag@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:423:462
Yf.prototype.open/this.Ia.onmessage@https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js:422:245
```